# Think Python - Exercise 4.3 #2

Tags: python

These are the questions. I successfully completed Question 1 but I am just adding it for context. I am having trouble with Question 2.

```
1. Write a function called square that takes a parameter named t, which is a turtle. It
should use the turtle to draw a square.
Write a function call that passes bob as an argument to square, and then run the
program again.
2. Add another parameter, named length, to square. Modify the body so length of the
sides is length, and then modify the function call to provide a second argument. Run
the program again. Test your program with a range of values for length.
```

Here is my work:

```
import turtle
bob = turtle.Turtle()
print(bob)

def square(t, length):
    for i in range(4):
        bob.fd(t, length)
        bob.lt(t)

square(bob, 200)

turtle.mainloop()
```

The following is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ivan/Documents/Python/thinkpython/square.py", line 10, in <module>
    square(bob, 200)
  File "/Users/ivan/Documents/Python/thinkpython/square.py", line 7, in square
    bob.fd(t, length)
TypeError: forward() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

The part I am not understanding in the traceback is that I only see two arguments given to bob.fd() but it's saying that it received three. Can someone explain this situation?

Comment: try `bob.fd(length)`

Comment: This worked! Thank you!

Comment: great I will add it as the answer with some explanation to it.  You have a few more mistakes in your code I will also explain in my answer. And welcome to stackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you! I am a medical student that decided to go into programming and I am self-studying so this is all very new to me. It's great to see such a helpful community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [forward function](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/turtle.html) `fd` only takes one argument `distance`

> turtle.fd(distance) Parameter:
>   distance – a number (integer or float)
>   Move the turtle forward by the specified distance, in the direction the turtle is headed.

1. In your case, you should only use your turtle instance `bob` and call `fd` with one argument in it like `t.fd(length)`
2. Also your turtle left turn function takes an integer or float not a turtle instance. so it should be like `t.lt(90)` if you want the turtle to turn 90 degrees.
3. your question asked you to pass in a turtle as as a parameter `t`. that is your turtle instance. That is why instead of calling `bob.fd()` and `bob.lt` we are calling `t.fd()` and `t.lt()`.

   ```
   import turtle
   bob = turtle.Turtle()
   print(bob)

   def square(t, length):
       for i in range(4):
           t.fd(length)
           t.lt(90)

   square(bob, 200)

   turtle.mainloop()
   ```

the above code should have the turtle `bob` draw a square of 200 by 200. 
Hope this helps. If you still don't understand leave a comment I will explain it in more detail.

Comment: I just made the edits and it all worked! However, question #2 asks us to add another parameter to square, so there should be two parameters for that function. I am still new to understanding how this works. The question also asks us modify the function call to provide a second argument, so we should be seeing two arguments in square(), correct?

Comment: haha I was editing the post when you post the comment. see if it makes sense

Comment: Thank you for the revisions! So when we call the function square(bob, 200) the variable bob is replacing the variable t and replacing within the body, correct?

Comment: ay! you got it! that is correct my friend ٩(๑❛ᴗ❛๑)۶

Comment: how beautiful it is!

Answer (score 1):

Because `bob` is an instantiation of the `Turtle` class and `fd` is a class function, there is an implicit `self` passed when the function is called. If you were to look at the definition for `fd` in the `Turtle` class, you would see something like `def fd(self, distance)`. When calling the class function `bob.fd(t, length)`, the `self` argument is passed with the instantiation of the class implicitly, and then you are passing 2 additional arguments `(t,length)`, for a total of 3 arguments.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I'll keep that in mind as I continue reading!